# Can you use PDFTextStripperByArea in an android app?

Tags: java, android, pdfbox

Is there a way to use Rectangle2D in android? PDFBox does only accept Rectangle2D and i dont find a way to use them in andorid.

Comment: Your question is unclear - could it be that what you really meant is that you want to use the code from PDFTextStripperByArea from PDFBox for desktop? If so, try "Rect": https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect

Comment: @TilmanHausherr yes, thats what i want to do. but it doesnt accept Rect. only Rectangle2d

Comment: Have you tried changing the source code of `PDFTextStripperByArea.java` and replace `Rectangle2D` with `Rect` ?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr i could do that, but i think that would be against the appache license. but thx

Comment: I don't see how it would be against the Apache license.

Comment: The Apache license is a very permissive license. If you did everything correctly to *use* the code then you can almost certainly modify it as well. Disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer, this is not legal advice. Talk to your licensing expert.